# When i try to run this script, i get a error: OverflowError: unsigned short is greater than maximum. Raspberry pi 4B, the sensor is DHT11

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi4

The code: (it is very small, just to test the sensor)

```
import adafruit_dht, board

print("Current temperature is " + str(adafruit_dht.DHT11(board.D21).temperature))
```

Full error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/murrakhm/Desktop/temp_v1.py", line 3, in <module>
    print("Current temperature is " + str(adafruit_dht.DHT11(board.D21).temperature))
  File "/home/murrakhm/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/adafruit_dht.py", line 274, in temperature
    self.measure()
  File "/home/murrakhm/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/adafruit_dht.py", line 219, in measure
    pulses = self._get_pulses_pulseio()
  File "/home/murrakhm/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/adafruit_dht.py", line 149, in _get_pulses_pulseio
    pulses.append(self.pulse_in.popleft())
OverflowError: unsigned short is greater than maximum
```

Comment: Show snippet code in line 149.

Answer (score 0):

The value the sensor (or some other part of your code) is returning is greater than 65535, which is the maximum value for an `unsigned short`.

I am not sure how to fix that, I do not have experience with raspberry pi sensors.

P.S. - An unsigned short is just a number type. `short` means it is 2 bytes, and `unsigned` means it must be positive (no +/- *sign*)